# Why are the spouts on some portafilters not aligned with the handle?

Tags: espresso-machine

On my Rancilio portafilter, the spouts are not aligned with the handle (I would expect them to be in a 90° angle). In consequence, the spouts do also not really align with the machine when the portafilter sits in the grouphead. Is there a specific rationale behind this?

[image]

Comment: Isn't the spout a threaded attachment? I think you can twist/unscrew it to either replace it (e.g., with a single spout) or adjust the position/angle...? E.g., [some replacement parts](https://www.espressoparts.com/search?q=Rancilio+spout). That would be strange if it were fixed at that angle...

Comment: Yes, but not without some effort. They seem to do this on purpose, it seems to be like that on all of their portafilters, not just mine.

Comment: My guess is that the spout threading was designed to line up correctly when using a specific rubber gasket.  Unscrew the spout and check to see if you have one, perhaps find a replacement if necessary?

Answer (score 2):

The spouts are aligned with the machine front and cup once the portafilter is installed for use in the machine. Note the handle on the portafilter body goes quite a distance over to the side, or it would interfere with handling the cup.